# Добавление даты билда в IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Нужно добавить дату билда.

Пишу properties

```
t5=${t5}
```

и pom

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create-timestamp</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <doCheck>false</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
        <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</timestampFormat>
        <timestampPropertyName>t5</timestampPropertyName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

с командной строки все работает. Получаю

```
t5=2019-07-12 15:54:04
```

при компиляции из IDEA получаю такое

```
t5=${t5}
```

Если забить на плагин `buildnumber-maven-plugin` и использовать `maven.build.timestamp.format`

```
<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <t3>${maven.build.timestamp}</t3>
</properties>
```

```
ts=${maven.build.timestamp}
t3=${t3}
```

Тогда при компиляции из IDEA получается

```
ts=2019-07-12 15:59:11
t3=2019-07-12 12:59:04
```

ts корректно, а t3 в часовом поясе UTC

А при компиляции из maven

```
ts=2019-07-12T13:02:29Z
t3=2019-07-12 13:02:27
```

ts не учитывает формат, а t3 идет по прежнему в UTC

Как бы это все подружить, чтобы работала как сборка из IDE, так и в maven?

Версия Maven в IDE и из командной строки совпадают

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`mvn -v`

> ```
> Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T18:41:47+02:00)
> Maven home: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3 Ultimate\plugins\maven\lib\maven3
> Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation
> Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2
> Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: UTF-8
> OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
> ```

Comment: Странные различия. Можете уточнить какая [версия maven](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/new-projects-from-scratch-maven-settings-page.html) используется в IDEA и какая вызывается из командной строки?

Comment: Я в свое время смирился с датой в UTC и преобразовывал ее при отображении :) Есть [костыли](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281988/how-to-have-maven-show-local-timezone-in-maven-build-timestamp), которые мне не очень понравились.

Comment: @defaultlocale IDEA [обещает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNTDL.png) 3.3.9. Она же отображается на `mvn -v` `Apache Maven 3.3.9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17861164/5376639) говорят, что это особенность работы идеи, которая хоть и тесно интегрируется с Maven, но имеет свои особенности и 100% сходства не бывает. И нужно собирать проект либо одним, либо другим

А [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37534728/5376639) рекомендуют добавить в Run Configuration IDEA задачу maven

Я добавил после `Build` задачу `generate-resources` и **при запуске** проекта стал получать properties файл идентичным запуску из командной строки. Такой вариант меня устроил